# ondragstart - setDragImage with dynamic element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a dynamic element that attaches to the cursor when you drag around images:

```
<img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?
q=tbn:ANd9GcTe_ojzFXmnZU1d5pK8XwIwKiRB3vE_8ifC7U4DXtzduwIlvgTLPzbTCw" id="img"/>

<div id="text" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px;">hello</div>

document.getElementById('img').ondragstart = function(e){
    var text = document.getElementById('text');
    text.innerHTML = 'foo';
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(text, 0, 0);
};
```

Since the element can't be created dynamically e.g. `document.createElement`, cloned etc, I had to place it off the screen as you can see above.

Obviusly I'm not happy with this solution. Do you guys have any ideas? I have jQuery at my disposal if that helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/WdkW5/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution which I think is good enough (assuming the browser supports canvas):

```
document.getElementById('img').ondragstart = function(e){

    var canvas = $('<canvas />').get(0),
        context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.fillStyle = 'blue';
    context.font = 'bold 16px Arial';
    context.fillText('hello world', 0, 16);

    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(canvas, -10, -10);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works without jQuery, similar to @Johan's although his didnt work for me, I had to call img.src = canvas.toDataURL();

```
document.getElementById('img').ondragstart = function(event){

    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.fillStyle = 'blue';
    context.font = 'bold 16px Arial';
    context.fillText('hello world', 0, 16);
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = canvas.toDataURL();

    event.dataTransfer.setDragImage(img, 0, 0);
};
```